# I need to modify the code of a python program to achieve exactly 245 iterations

Tags: python, iteration, primes

I am working on a project for school, and I am very new to python. I am struggling with a portion of my project where I have coded a program to calculate the prime numbers between 1 - 100. One of the requirements for a higher grade is to make this program achieve this in exactly 245 iterations of the loop, by only modifying line 4. I am currentlty getting 139. Here is what I have so far:

```
def is_prime(num):
    if num < 2:
        return False
    the_end = int(num ** 0.5) + 1
    for i in range(2, the_end):
        if num % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

print("The 25 prime numbers between 1 and 100:")
count = 0
for num in range(1, 101):
    if is_prime(num):
        count = count + 1
        print(count, num)
```

Any help would be greatly apreciated, I am really enjoying learning python so far!

The code i started with is:

```
def is_prime(num):
    if num < 2:
        return False
    the_end = num
    for i in range(2, the_end):
        if num % i == 0:
            return False
        return True
    
print("The 25 numbers between 1 and 100:")
count = 0
for num in range(1, 101):
    if is_prime(num):
        count = count + 1
        print(count, num)
```

I modified it to what I put above in my question, which resulted in 139 iterations.

Comment: If you’re doing it more efficiently now why would you want to do it less so? Have you checked with your teacher? Surely they’d be happy you found a better way?

Comment: Which is line 4?

Comment: Unrelated to this exercise, but this is *not* the Sieve of Eratosthenes.

Comment: 139? I just ran your code and it returns 236! How are you counting?

Comment: Besides 2, you know that no other even number is prime. So, don't check.

Comment: So, what are you counting? Nothing counts 139 or 236, much less 245.

Comment: @tdelaney You get 236 if you increment a global counter in the `for` loop in `is_prime()`

Comment: @tdelaney If you only check odd factors, iterations drops to 87, which isn't the goal.

Comment: @adamsmith Ah, my apologies. I have been doing some research online and I mixed it up with another method.

Comment: @bob I'm not sure, it is an odd requirement I agree.

Comment: @treuss this is the code wrote to have it output the iterations:' def is_prime(num):
    if num < 2:
        return False
    the_end = int(num ** 0.5) + 1
    for i in range(2, the_end):
        if num % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

print("The 25 prime numbers between 1 and 100:")
count = 0
total = 0 # initialize total to zero
for num in range(1, 101):
    if is_prime(num):
        count = count + 1
        print(count, num)
        total = total + int(num ** 0.5) # add loop executions for num to total
print("The total number of iterations is:", total)'

Comment: By the way, this is the video explaining the requirements for the grade if you guys are interested: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FihjSKEuEyM

Comment: @Blaarg your instructor's quote in that video is "modify line 4 such that it works with less effort." The bits about the _exact_ iteration count seem irrelevant.

Comment: @adamsmith If you look at the graphic that he outs up around 4:13 it says "To move your grade from an A to an A+ you will need to modify line 4 to cause exactly 245 iterations to solve the same problem.

Comment: @Blaarg I'm reading the text, but it seems irrelevant given his verbal instruction.

Comment: @AdamSmith I don't want to chance it given the written instructions. I will contact him and clarify.

Comment: As it is, your code runs 237 iterations (assuming an iteration is a single time through the is_prime loop, and counting even if it early-outs when num < 2). You could game that to give the desired output, but it's kinda...terrible to do that :D

Comment: @AdamSmith Ok, thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 0):

As discussed at length in the comments, you should clarify with your instructor as 245 seems like a silly iteration count (it doesn't correspond with any sort of optimization you might be guided towards).

*HOWEVER*, you could tweak your code to produce that result if you're not afraid of writing terrible unnecessary code!

```py
import math

def is_prime(num):
    global counter
    if num < 2:
        counter += 1
        return False
    the_end = math.isqrt(num) + (1 if num != 17 else 9)
    for i in range(2, the_end):
        counter += 1
        if num % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    counter = 0
    for num in range(1, 101):
        _ = is_prime(num)
    print(counter)  # 245
```

This counts a single iteration whenever num is less than two and whenever num's modularity is compared. What was line 4 (`the_end = ...`) is toyed with to give an arbitrary number of extra iterations on a known-prime term.

Perhaps notably, if you wanted to meet your instructor's requirement to hit exactly 665 iterations, then

```py
the_end = num // 2 + 3
```

Will do that, but `3` is just as arbitrary as `(1 if num != 17 else 9)`

Comment: I totally agree that it is silly, I think what he is trying to get at is there is some method we have learned that will work to make it exactly that. And he wants us to do it while ONLY modifying line 4. Thats just my hunch.